# How use a vector list with commands in order to send to CreateProcess?

Tags: c++, windows, vector, char, createprocess

I want a script for passing a vector list that is consisting of commands in order to create a process.

```
vector<string> list;
list.push.back(eeee -q 50  kekekekkee.jpg -o  kdkdkdkdd.jpg);
list.push.back(eeee -q 50  kefffffee.jpg -o  kefffffee.jpg);
list.push.back(eeee -q 50  kfffffff.jpg -o  kfffffff.jp);
list.push.back(eeee -q 50  kekeksfwefee.jpg -o  kekeksfwefee.jpg);

/* YOUR MAGICAL CODE HERE */

if (CreateProcessA(NULL, ?????, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

Does someone has a solution for this /any idea  how to do this?

Comment: A "script"? Ist there a C++ scripting engine available?

Comment: What kind of syntax are these `eeee -q 50  kekekekkee.jpg -o  kdkdkdkdd.jpg` lines?

Comment: I normally use command line arguments for this which is a single string parameter. If you have the source of the program you are starting you can also add a file option to your command line arguments and then put all the other command line arguments in a file generated from your application that needs to call CreateProcess().

Comment: it's a concept of comand line

Answer (score 1):

First, your `std::vector::push_back` call needs strings.

```
list.push_back("eeee -q 50  kekekekkee.jpg -o  kdkdkdkdd.jpg");
list.push_back("eeee -q 50  kefffffee.jpg -o  kefffffee.jpg");
list.push_back("eeee -q 50  kfffffff.jpg -o  kfffffff.jpg");
list.push_back("eeee -q 50  kekeksfwefee.jpg -o  kekeksfwefee.jpg");
```

Then just loop through the vector

```
for(auto&& ProcessArgs : list) 
{
   // So about CreateProcessA, it is a wrapper for CreateProcessW.
   // Normally the string being fed into CreateProcess must be mutable, but
   // in the case of CreateProcessA, a copy is made and converted to unicode to 
   // call CreateProcessW. Meaning we can give our string directly from
   // the std::string without needing to make a copy.
   // However, the way to do that is to use const_cast to remove the 
   // constness of std::string::c_str, so lets not and make a copy
   // anyway, because const_cast is bad practice.

   std::unique_ptr<char*> spString(new char[ProcessArgs.length() + 1]());
   std::copy(ProcessArgs.begin(), ProcessArgs.end(), spString.get());

   if (CreateProcessA(NULL, spString.get(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
   {
      CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
      CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
   } 
}
```

Comment: you have more errors in your code !  see my answar . and thx for your time and your point of view!

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
vector<string list;
//populate vector
list.push_back("eeee -q 50  kekekekkee.jpg -o  kdkdkdkdd.jpg");
list.push_back("eeee -q 50  kefffffee.jpg -o  kefffffee.jpg");
list.push_back("eeee -q 50  kfffffff.jpg -o  kfffffff.jpg");
list.push_back("eeee -q 50  kekeksfwefee.jpg -o  kekeksfwefee.jpg");


for( int am =0; (unsigned)am < dirlist.size(); am++){

STARTUPINFOA si = {sizeof(STARTUPINFOA), 0};
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};

cout <<endl;

        char myArray[list.size() +1];
        strcpy(myArray,list[am].c_str());
if (CreateProcessA(NULL,myArray, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
}
return 0;
}
```

this is working 100% tested!!
carefull with how many cmd line without restriction max threads !